# Generic transformations of nested data structures

Tags: java, data-structures

There are two kind of transformations I want to apply to some nested datastructures:

1. Map<X, Map<Y, Z>> to transform into a Map<Y, Map<X, Z>>

For example:

```
Map.of("a", Map.of("X", 1, "Y", 2), 
       "b", Map.of("Y", 3))
```

should be transformed to

```
Map.of("X", Map.of("a", 1),
       "Y", Map.of("a", 2, "b", 3))
```

2. Map<X, Set> to transform into a Map<Y, Set>

For example:

```
Map.of("a", Set.of("X", "Y"), 
       "b", Set.of("Y", "Z"))
```

should be transformed to

```
Map.of("X", Set.of("a"),
       "Y", Set.of("a", "b"),
       "Z", Set.of("b"))
```

I don't know the names of these transformations, and I don't find implementations for them in any of the JVM languages I use (Java mainly, Groovy and Clojure sometimes), probably because I don't know what to look for.
They seem rather general problems and I would expect to be very well known and have solutions already present in libraries or even SDK.
The first one is a "transpose" I guess, as a map of maps can be viewed as a matrix.

Comment: Hi, can you formulate this as a question?
What do you want? a way to implement that? or a library that has that already implemented?

Comment: why there are 3 different languages in tags?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for Guava [Tables.transpose](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Tables.html#transpose(com.google.common.collect.Table)).

Comment: I have removed [groovy] and [clojure] because OPs code looks like Java and the others where just referenced in the text.

Comment: I don't think this transformation has a specific name. Mathematically, you want to transform a [set-valued function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-valued_function) to its inverse function.

Answer (score 1):

```
    // Transpose a map of maps
Map<Y, Map<X, Z>> transpose(Map<X, Map<Y, Z>> map) {
  Map<Y, Map<X, Z>> transposed = new HashMap<>();
  for (Map.Entry<X, Map<Y, Z>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    for (Map.Entry<Y, Z> innerEntry : entry.getValue().entrySet()) {
      transposed.computeIfAbsent(innerEntry.getKey(), k -> new HashMap<>()).put(entry.getKey(), innerEntry.getValue());
    }
  }
  return transposed;
}

// Flatten a map of sets
Map<Y, Set> flatten(Map<X, Set> map) {
  Map<Y, Set> flattened = new HashMap<>();
  for (Map.Entry<X, Set> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    flattened.computeIfAbsent(entry.getKey(), k -> new HashSet<>()).addAll(entry.getValue());
  }
  return flattened;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you will find such transpose OPs in widely available libraries, but it's fairly easy to model them in plain Groovy:

```
def inp1 = [ a:[ X:1, Y:2 ], b:[ Y:3 ] ]
def res1 = inp1.inject( [:].withDefault{ [:] } ){ res, k, v ->
  v.each{ kk, vv -> res[ kk ][ k ] = vv  }
  res
}

assert res1.toString() == '[X:[a:1], Y:[a:2, b:3]]'

// -------------------------

def inp2 = [ a:[ "X", "Y" ] as Set, b:[ "Y", "Z" ] as Set ]
def res2 = inp2.inject( [:].withDefault{ new HashSet() } ){ res, k, v ->
  v.each{ vv -> res[ vv ] << k }
  res
}
assert res2.toString() == '[X:[a], Y:[a, b], Z:[b]]'
assert Set.isAssignableFrom( res2.X.class )
```

Answer (score 0):

In Clojure, the transformations would look something like:

```clj
(defn rotate-map [m]
  (reduce-kv (fn [m k1 m2]
               (reduce-kv (fn [m k2 v] (assoc-in m [k2 k1] v)) m m2))
  {} m))

(defn rotate-set [m]
  (reduce-kv (fn [m k s]
               (reduce (fn [m x]
                         (update m x (fnil conj #{}) k))
                       m s))
             {} m))
```

testing:

```clj
user=> (rotate-map '{a {x 1 y 2} b {y 3}})
{x {a 1}, y {a 2, b 3}}

user=> (rotate-set '{x #{a} y #{a b} z #{b}})
{a #{x y}, b #{y z}}
```